# Button click code behind processing works in localhost, but not when loaded up to Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, windows-server-2012

I have the following button click event on a page that calls a service, validates a user, and redirects to another page. In localhost, I have no problems, everything acts as it should, but when I push this up to a `Windows Server 2012` dev server, on button click, the browser gets stuck processing. I've canceled out the service not working, because I can hit it from both localhost and hitting the uploaded service on the Windows server with Fiddler.

When I click the button on the dev site, the browser debugger network tab shows everything to be pending, and I have no console errors. I've tried to rebuild the solution to see if there are any missing assemblies, but everything looks fine there. I honestly am at a loss because I see nothing wrong anywhere. I'm not sure where to go from here, so any advice or questions would help me out a lot.

```
    protected async void btnCustSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://XXXXXXXX/WebServiceAddress/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var auth = new Auth {Email = txtUserEmail.Text, Password = txtCustPassword.Text};
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Auth/ValidateUser", auth);
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            //Unimportant code
            Response.Redirect("Portal.aspx", false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess you are using Web API as the service platform. How have you hosted it? Is it part of the same application or is it self hosted?

Comment: I am using Web API and it is self hosted.

Comment: Can you verify that it's working as expected? Maybe try tracing http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: I'm pretty sure its working because I use both Fiddler and a localhost client to hit the service, and it performs the way its supposed to.

Comment: Don't you need to `await` the call to `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`?

Comment: Whereas adding `await` to `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` works on localhost, publishing the change up to the server doesn't fix my current issue.